# Device orientation with accelerometer and magnetometer and gyro

Tags: matrices

I'm struggling with my math, I'm doing a project looking at an individual's hand movements whilst performing specific surgical tasks.

In my initial experiment I only had to record.angle in one axis.  In this experiment the hand can now move in all 3 axis.  I have an accelerometer,gyro and magnetometer.

I think quaternions would be the best to avoid gimbal lock with Euler's.  I can't work out how to fit.my.values into the matrices to produce a quaternion.
The Accel is XYZ, in g/s.  The magnetometer is XYZ in gauss.  I should be able to use those to readings to orient my.device in 3 axis and then I can combine the gyro with my complimentary filter I already have.

Can anyone help explain or point out how I may achieve this I'm totally flooded with reading online guides and complex explanations.

Thank you
Ian

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackExchange. Can you describe exactly what you want to achieve? If you want to achieve *understanding*, that may be a challenge: maybe all those complex explanations you've found are complex because the topic is complex. If you just want to determine orientation from a sequence of magnetometer and accelerometer readings, would working code be enough? Because this has been done a *lot* of times, for almost every drone ever built, for instance. Let us know what you really need, and maybe we can help.

Comment: Code would be good.  I'm using max/map as my interface.  It would also be fine to apply a formula to excel data retrospectively.

Comment: I'm probably as code-savvy as any "math person" here (I've been teaching computer science for about 30 years), but "max/map" doesn't instantly mean anything to me. Perhaps you can elaborate in your question so that the folks who want to help can do so without doing lots of extra work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that takes magnetometer, gyro, and acceleration data from a 9 degree of freedom sensor and produces pose data. It's for an arduino-based setup, but the code is pretty much ordinary "C" code, and should be readily adaptable.

https://github.com/richardstechnotes/RTIMULib2

Comment: Max from cycling7 is the coding platform I have been using for my device.  It has an intrinsic function to convert angles to quaternions but I wasn't sure if that would still have error but I think from my reading I still need to tabulate the tilt values then input those into a quaternion formula.

Comment: Y'know, if you want to be **helpful** in situations like this, you include a *link* rather than expecting me to either know about your platform or go google it for myself. If you're sure that the angle-to-quaternion code in your platform has errors, maybe you should stop using that platform. If you're sure there's a quaternion formula out there, just waiting for your data...so be it. I wish you the best of luck in finding it. I'm an expert on quaternions and graphics, but don't let that stop you and your certainty.  I've given you a pointer to working code; do with it what you want.

Comment: Sorry John, I certainly wasn't trying to be rude.  I am appreciative for the help.

Comment: http://wizmoz.blogspot.com/2013/01/simple-accelerometer-data-conversion-to.html?m=1 this is the math I had been using to calculate my angles.  My understanding is that I need the 3 axis tilts plus a fourth to make a quaternion.  I will take some time and look through the coding you have provided.  Thank you

Comment: A rotation $R$ described by 3 Euler angles can also be described by a unit quaternion.  It's a little subtle, though, because if $R$ is describe by $q$, it's also described by $-q$. But there's no need for a fourth number. The rotation-to-quaternion transformation can be done through the inverse of Rodrigues' formula, for example. This is described in some detail in *Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice*; I know because I wrote that chapter. Other books are surely equally good. But it's clear from your comments that you need to learn a bit more about quaternions, or just use...

Comment: ..a library that takes care of the quaternion understanding for you, like the one I pointed you to. There's really no middle ground where you "kinda understand quaternions" and write a stable and sophisticated sensor-fusion algorithm based on them.

Comment: My issue with the system I have so far is that it works very well as long as pitch is not too extreme.  The device I'm trying to orientate is fixed to the back of someone's hand.  So in the neutral position ie. The thumbs up position the device is either at 90 degrees pitch or roll depending on the direction it's fixed.  So really my problem is more with how to measure the orientation rather than how it's represented.  Using my 3 accelerometer readings when orientated at 90 degrees my device in parallel to y axis which then nullifies roll or pitch.  I think I need to cross reference with

Comment: The magnetometer which orientated to 90 degrees to gravity so now when the device accuracy diminishes from the accelerometer it should be increasing with the magnetometer.  Does that sound right?  I think I believed that quaternions would fix that but I think no matter how I represent the angle the measurement technique is still the same.  So if I used north and gravity as my two reference points I think then my device would produce the results I require.